# injecting dependency through factory in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have below service code

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('App')
           .factory('apiservice', apiservice);

    /* @ngInject */
    function apiservice($http) {
        var service = {
            getData: getGridData,
        };

        return service;

       //code ommitted for clarity
    }
})();
```

When I minifying and bundling, the dependency is getting screwed up. So I wanted to change **$scope** to **'$scope'** so minifier won't mess up with name.

I know there are several ways to do it. But can I make it work like below:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('App')
           .factory('apiservice', ['http', apiservice]);

    function apiservice($http) {
        return service;
    }
})();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options,. the first is to use the extended syntax for dependency injection. In this case:

```
.factory('apiservice', ['$http', apiservice]);

function apiservice($http) {
  return service;
}
```

This can also be written as:

```
.factory('apiservice', apiservice);

apiservice.$inject = ['$http'];

function apiservice($http) {
  return service;
}
```

---

Or put add another build step before you minify, such as [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) which will convert your syntax to the extended version.

A factory like this

```
.factory('apiservice', function($http) {
  return service;
});
```

Would become:

```
.factory('apiservice', ['$http', function($http) {
  return service;
});
```

Which would be safe to minify.

Comment: Thanks..I used your very first approach. Now I am not getting different errors like 1)  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"                               2) "TypeError: apiservice.getTestData is not a function"

Comment: That will be to do with whatever you return from your `.factory(apiservice', function() { ... })` function. If you update to show what `service` is when you return it, I'll take a look.

Comment: Yes but it started coming after I minified and bundled the files. The problem is its not recognizing the dependencies. The first error is coming on $http.get(). Its not finding $http, hence shouting 'get' of undefined.

Comment: If you use the `['$http', function($http) { }]` syntax, that can't happen.